# How to get a List<Bitmap> from asset folder in Kotlin

Tags: arraylist, kotlin, bitmap

How to init a list of Bitmaps from asset folder. I have a folder in assets called "images" with multiple PNG images:

E:\Computer Projects\Android\TaskProgress\app\src\main\assets\images

My code:

```
class Icons(val context: Context)
{
    companion object
    {
        lateinit var iconList : MutableList<Bitmap>
    }

    init
    {
        iconList = ???
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I implemented this by the following:

```
class Icons(var context: Context)
{
    init
    {
        val assetManager = context.assets
        try
        {
            var `is`: InputStream
            var files = assetManager.list("boys")
            for(i in files!!.indices)
            {
                `is` = assetManager.open("boys/" + files[i])
                val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(`is`)
                iconListBoys.add(i, bitmap)
            }
            files = assetManager.list("girls")
            for(i in files!!.indices)
            {
                `is` = assetManager.open("girls/" + files[i])
                val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(`is`)
                iconListGirls.add(i, bitmap)
            }
        }
        catch (e: IOException)
        {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }

    companion object
    {
        var iconListBoys: ArrayList<Bitmap> = ArrayList()
        var iconListGirls: ArrayList<Bitmap> = ArrayList()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**I am not in Android Environment right now, so below code might not work.**

**Please leave a comment if so.**

You need to have `Context` to work with assets.

So rather than initializing `iconList` with declaration,

I'll add `load()` method to load the list of assets.

**Icons class**

Icons class will look like below if you add `load()` method.

```
class Icons {
    companion object {
        // initialize with empty list
        var iconList = listOf<Bitmap>()

        fun load(context: Context) {
            // This is where we will load assets
        }
    }
}
```

**load() method**

First in `load()` method, we will get list of file names in *`assets/list`*.

1. `context.getAssets()` will return `AssetManager` object.
2. `AssetManager.list(subPath)` will return all files in *`subPath`*.
3. use `map()` to convert list of file name String to list of Bitmap.
4. `AssetManager.open(filePath)` to open `InputStream` from file.
5. `BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream)` to create `Bitmap` from `InputStream`

With those, it will be

```
val am = context.getAssets()
iconList = am.list("images").map { 
    val inputStream = am.open("images/$it")
    return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream)
}
```

Comment: listOf is an unresolved reference; the return code is expecting a Unit but is returning Bitmap!

Comment: @Samuel `listOf` unresolved? `listOf` is built in method in Kotlin and if you have error with it, please check your kotlin plugin if it is correctly set. Do you mean `listOf<Bitmap>()` causes compile error?